# How do I filter an empty DataFrame and still keep the columns of that DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of why pandas is a terribly <del>designed</del> hacked together library:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1,2,3]
df['B'] = [4,5,6]
print(df)

df1 = df[df.A.apply(lambda x:x == 4)]
df2 = df1[df1.B.apply(lambda x:x == 1)]
print(df2)
```

This will print

```
df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
df2
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Note how `Columns: []` , which means any further/selecting on `df2` will fail. This is a huge issue, because it means I now have to ***always*** check if any table is empty before attempting to select from it, which is garbage behaviour.

For clarity, the sensible, thoughtful, reasonable, not totally broken behaviour would be to preserve the columns.

Anyone care to offer some hack I can apply on top of the collection of hacks which is the dataframe API?

Comment: I expect `Columns: [A, B]` to be in the output. I know I can do `df.A == 4` in this particular case, but not all apply calls can be replaced like that, so that's not providing an answer.

Comment: Although the tone of the question seems a bit aggressive, I think it's a really beneficial discussion. It shows a common trap that's easy to fall into when working with Pandas. Remember, if you're filtering dataframes (empty or not), using `.loc` clears up a lot of the ambiguities associated with row vs column operations. Lesson learned: Always look beyond the tone to the substance of the question. We're all here to learn after all! Happy coding 

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
df2 = df1[df1.B.apply(lambda x:x == 1).astype(bool)]
```

All other answers are missing the point (except for Wen's, which is an ok alternative)

Comment: What is happening is that you are using `__getitem__` (namely, `[]`) with an empty series.  Pandas is interpreting that as a slice of the columns.  By using `astype(bool)` you are forcing Pandas to interpreting it as a row boolean slice.

Answer (score 5):

***Pandas almost consider all situations we need, especially for those simple cases***

PS: Nothing wrong with pandas

```
df1 = df.loc[df.A.apply(lambda x:x == 4)]
df2 = df1.loc[df1.B.apply(lambda x:x == 1)]
df1
Out[53]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
df2
Out[54]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

Comment: This is the answer I was thinking of.  Using `[]` for boolean selection gets us into the ambiguities of column slicing versus row slicing (which I'm not motivated to detail).  Using `.loc` makes our goal clear (we don't even need the `,:`).